# fillbetween from pgfplots does not work inside groupplots

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots, fillbetween

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
t lineLow lineHigh lineMedian
0 1 1 1
1 2 2 2
2 2 3 2.5
3 2 4 3
4 2 4 3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}
    [
        group style={group size=1 by 2, vertical sep=30pt}
    ]
        \nextgroupplot
        [
        ]

        \addplot[name path=lineLow] table[x=t, y=lineLow] {testdata.dat};
        \addplot[name path=lineHigh] table[x=t, y=lineHigh] {testdata.dat};
        \addplot[fill=red] fill between[of=lineLow and lineHigh];
        \addplot table[x=t, y=lineMedian] {testdata.dat};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[name path=lineLow] table[x=t, y=lineLow] {testdata.dat};
        \addplot[name path=lineHigh] table[x=t, y=lineHigh] {testdata.dat};
        \addplot[fill=red] fill between[of=lineLow and lineHigh];
        \addplot table[x=t, y=lineMedian] {testdata.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Problem: the fill area between the lines does not work inside `groupplots`. Is there a workaround for this?

Versions:

- pgf 3.0.0
- pgfplots 1.11

Comment: Any chances to get this working? I'd really like to use it in my paper.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved by updating PGFPlots to v1.14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in `pgfplots 1.11`. I downgraded to `pgfplots 1.10` and everything looks as expected.

Comment: The bug appears to be related to layered graphics, more specifically to `cell picture=false`. If you add `set layers,cell picture=true,` to your `groupplot`, it will also work for 1.11 . I will look into it.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Are there any updates on this? I just came across this same bug and I'm using `pgfplots` 1.12. Good that I found this comment of yours for a workaround!

Comment: No, this is still current at the time of this writing (latest stable 1.12.1).

Answer (score 3):

The bug has been fixed in pgfplots version 1.13. With 1.13, the example compiles as expected without any changes: [image]

At the time of this writing (January 9, 2016), version 1.13 is quite fresh and might need a couple of days until it arrives in all TeX package managers.

Comment: Unfortunately, `fillbetween` still does not seem to work correctly in all sub-plots inside a group plot on my setup even with PGFPlots 1.13. For instance, [this LaTeX file](https://ptpb.pw/sFaC/latex) results in [this PDF file](https://ptpb.pw/mDQe.pdf). Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: Another appearance of the same issue: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287424

Comment: @ib I have analyzed your issue and found that it is caused by a different, unrelated root cause. Apparently, two axes in the same figure suffer from the fact that the first `fill between` installs a clip path -- and the second is clipped away. This is clearly a bug and I will take care of it. A workaround is to add `clip=false` to the `groupplot` environment.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi my last comment (and workaround) applies to your example as well.

Comment: same with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227775/pgfplot-image-messed-up-with-newer-texlive

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Thank you very much for taking time to look into this (and working on PGFPlot, in general)! I’ll keep an eye on future releases.

Comment: @ib pgfplots 1.14 is out. I am confident that it is resolved and would like you to verify that the issues are gone.

Comment: I seem to run into this on 1.15, but only when using beamer. Workaround `set layers,cell picture=true` works.