# Pgfplot image messed up with newer texlive

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

**EDIT:** The question has been marked as duplicate, since the fillbetween not working in groupplots is a known issue in pgfplots newer than 1.10. But the question remains, that why doesn't using `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}` solve this?

I installed (as a user) a newer texlive on a server, than the one I use on my computer.

I have the following code (compiled with lualatex):

```
\documentclass[class=scrartcl,14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmathfont{Arial}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}


\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.001000000000000000e+03 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.001000000000000000e+03 1.393999999999999961e-01 1.089399999999999952e-01 1.598050000000000026e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.001000000000000000e+03 2.077499999999999902e-01 1.971475000000000033e-01 2.176500000000000101e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.001000000000000000e+03 2.186250000000000138e-01 2.098974999999999869e-01 2.270500000000000018e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.001000000000000000e+03 2.204000000000000126e-01 2.109475000000000100e-01 2.292500000000000093e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.001000000000000000e+03 2.177999999999999936e-01 2.086850000000000094e-01 2.270000000000000073e-01 2.174999999999999850e-03 5.000000000000000104e-04 5.100000000000000366e-03
7.001000000000000000e+03 2.184500000000000053e-01 2.081000000000000072e-01 2.275449999999999973e-01 1.949999999999999910e-03 2.000000000000000096e-04 6.100000000000000387e-03
8.001000000000000000e+03 2.172000000000000042e-01 2.073500000000000065e-01 2.266174999999999995e-01 1.899999999999999996e-03 1.000000000000000048e-04 7.117499999999999695e-03
9.001000000000000000e+03 2.175249999999999961e-01 2.075849999999999917e-01 2.269150000000000056e-01 1.850000000000000082e-03 9.249999999999999867e-05 8.200000000000000691e-03
1.000100000000000000e+04 2.170749999999999902e-01 2.064999999999999891e-01 2.267975000000000130e-01 2.000000000000000042e-03 1.000000000000000048e-04 9.197500000000000814e-03
1.100100000000000000e+04 2.168499999999999872e-01 2.063500000000000056e-01 2.263000000000000012e-01 2.200000000000000133e-03 1.000000000000000048e-04 1.105000000000000079e-02
1.200100000000000000e+04 2.165249999999999952e-01 2.048375000000000057e-01 2.270149999999999946e-01 2.449999999999999921e-03 1.000000000000000048e-04 1.179999999999999973e-02
1.300100000000000000e+04 2.161500000000000088e-01 2.048500000000000043e-01 2.258300000000000030e-01 2.700000000000000143e-03 1.000000000000000048e-04 1.204000000000000035e-02
1.400100000000000000e+04 2.159999999999999976e-01 2.040150000000000019e-01 2.261450000000000127e-01 3.050000000000000194e-03 1.499999999999999869e-04 1.349500000000000005e-02
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data2.dat}
1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.001000000000000000e+03 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.001000000000000000e+03 1.393999999999999961e-01 1.089399999999999952e-01 1.598050000000000026e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.001000000000000000e+03 2.077499999999999902e-01 1.971475000000000033e-01 2.176500000000000101e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.001000000000000000e+03 2.186250000000000138e-01 2.098974999999999869e-01 2.270500000000000018e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.001000000000000000e+03 2.204000000000000126e-01 2.109475000000000100e-01 2.292500000000000093e-01 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.001000000000000000e+03 2.153500000000000136e-01 2.057950000000000057e-01 2.251549999999999940e-01 5.599999999999999943e-03 1.745000000000000023e-03 1.295499999999999950e-02
7.001000000000000000e+03 2.101000000000000090e-01 1.942399999999999960e-01 2.224599999999999911e-01 1.359999999999999924e-02 2.739999999999999814e-03 3.477000000000000229e-02
8.001000000000000000e+03 1.975999999999999979e-01 1.646700000000000108e-01 2.177399999999999891e-01 3.185000000000000331e-02 5.335000000000000332e-03 7.951500000000000234e-02
9.001000000000000000e+03 1.718000000000000083e-01 1.193000000000000033e-01 2.112249999999999961e-01 6.940000000000000335e-02 1.305000000000000084e-02 1.462749999999999884e-01
1.000100000000000000e+04 1.287999999999999978e-01 7.374999999999999611e-02 1.962899999999999923e-01 1.289500000000000091e-01 3.244999999999999968e-02 2.115200000000000136e-01
1.100100000000000000e+04 8.147500000000000575e-02 3.836749999999999883e-02 1.695250000000000090e-01 1.985750000000000015e-01 7.426499999999999768e-02 2.616324999999999901e-01
1.200100000000000000e+04 4.440000000000000197e-02 1.840249999999999872e-02 1.262675000000000047e-01 2.504000000000000115e-01 1.380474999999999897e-01 2.905325000000000268e-01
1.300100000000000000e+04 2.164999999999999911e-02 7.817499999999999796e-03 7.922999999999999488e-02 2.845500000000000251e-01 2.019749999999999879e-01 3.071825000000000250e-01
1.400100000000000000e+04 9.650000000000000591e-03 3.017500000000000217e-03 4.343000000000000332e-02 3.001499999999999724e-01 2.539449999999999763e-01 3.158799999999999941e-01
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data3.dat}
1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.001000000000000000e+03 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.001000000000000000e+03 1.460000000000000013e-02 4.197499999999999842e-03 2.730250000000000038e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.001000000000000000e+03 2.717500000000000124e-02 1.113250000000000003e-02 3.660499999999999865e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.001000000000000000e+03 3.052500000000000005e-02 1.990000000000000102e-02 3.870250000000000079e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.001000000000000000e+03 3.139999999999999736e-02 2.214750000000000052e-02 3.955249999999999738e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.001000000000000000e+03 3.155000000000000165e-02 2.375000000000000028e-02 3.915249999999999980e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.001000000000000000e+03 3.192500000000000199e-02 2.429500000000000062e-02 3.944999999999999896e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.001000000000000000e+03 2.985000000000000153e-02 2.220000000000000098e-02 3.725250000000000089e-02 2.749999999999999840e-03 8.499999999999999526e-04 6.702500000000000124e-03
9.001000000000000000e+03 2.895000000000000004e-02 2.056749999999999898e-02 3.723250000000000171e-02 2.500000000000000052e-03 2.000000000000000096e-04 9.782499999999999529e-03
1.000100000000000000e+04 2.794999999999999915e-02 1.907500000000000168e-02 3.610000000000000014e-02 2.399999999999999790e-03 5.000000000000000240e-05 1.187500000000000014e-02
1.100100000000000000e+04 2.744999999999999871e-02 1.590000000000000094e-02 3.700250000000000067e-02 2.724999999999999992e-03 1.000000000000000048e-04 1.332000000000000024e-02
1.200100000000000000e+04 2.732499999999999860e-02 1.389999999999999916e-02 3.645000000000000323e-02 2.925000000000000083e-03 1.000000000000000048e-04 1.596500000000000002e-02
1.300100000000000000e+04 2.634999999999999842e-02 1.177500000000000074e-02 3.596250000000000141e-02 3.449999999999999942e-03 5.000000000000000240e-05 1.818749999999999881e-02
1.400100000000000000e+04 2.552499999999999908e-02 1.000500000000000000e-02 3.497249999999999664e-02 4.599999999999999922e-03 1.424999999999999943e-04 2.038749999999999937e-02
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data4.dat}
1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.001000000000000000e+03 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
2.001000000000000000e+03 1.460000000000000013e-02 4.197499999999999842e-03 2.730250000000000038e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
3.001000000000000000e+03 2.717500000000000124e-02 1.113250000000000003e-02 3.660499999999999865e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
4.001000000000000000e+03 3.052500000000000005e-02 1.990000000000000102e-02 3.870250000000000079e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
5.001000000000000000e+03 3.139999999999999736e-02 2.214750000000000052e-02 3.955249999999999738e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
6.001000000000000000e+03 3.155000000000000165e-02 2.375000000000000028e-02 3.915249999999999980e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
7.001000000000000000e+03 3.192500000000000199e-02 2.429500000000000062e-02 3.944999999999999896e-02 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
8.001000000000000000e+03 2.910000000000000087e-02 2.109750000000000167e-02 3.640000000000000180e-02 6.049999999999999822e-03 1.897500000000000098e-03 1.345000000000000015e-02
9.001000000000000000e+03 2.485000000000000056e-02 1.513499999999999915e-02 3.420499999999999929e-02 1.305000000000000084e-02 2.050000000000000173e-03 3.030000000000000054e-02
1.000100000000000000e+04 1.962500000000000008e-02 8.899999999999999925e-03 3.219999999999999946e-02 2.390000000000000110e-02 2.599999999999999881e-03 4.624999999999999944e-02
1.100100000000000000e+04 1.319999999999999993e-02 4.060000000000000241e-03 2.938999999999999946e-02 3.774999999999999883e-02 5.449999999999999983e-03 5.909999999999999976e-02
1.200100000000000000e+04 7.649999999999999682e-03 1.299999999999999940e-03 2.605000000000000024e-02 4.984999999999999848e-02 1.220000000000000077e-02 6.619999999999999496e-02
1.300100000000000000e+04 3.899999999999999821e-03 2.999999999999999737e-04 2.125250000000000056e-02 5.787500000000000283e-02 2.262499999999999928e-02 7.080000000000000182e-02
1.400100000000000000e+04 1.699999999999999905e-03 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.285000000000000031e-02 6.235000000000000264e-02 3.817000000000000254e-02 7.255749999999999700e-02
\end{filecontents}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{100, 0, 150}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{34, 139, 34}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
%~ \begin{preview}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2, horizontal sep=2cm,
xlabels at=edge bottom
},
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
scaled y ticks = false,
scaled x ticks = false,
%~ xlabel=time (week),
xlabel=time (year),
xtick pos=left,
ytick pos=left,
]




\nextgroupplot[legend columns=-1,legend style={{draw=none,column sep=1ex, at={(2,1.3), anchor=north west},
/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=5cm}}},
legend entries={first strain, second strain},
ymax = 0.35,
ymin = -0.05,
ytick= {0,0.1,0.2,0.3},
minor y tick num = {1},
%~ xtick ={1000,5000},
xtick ={0,5218,10436,15654},
xticklabels={$0$,$100$,$200$,$300$}
]
%to switch to years divide be 52.18
\addlegendimage{no markers,myblue,line width=2.0}
\addlegendimage{no markers,myred,line width=2.0,loosely dashed}

\addplot[color=myblue, line width = 1.0] table[x index=0, y index=1] {data.dat};
\addplot[color=myred, line width = 1.0,loosely dashed] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data.dat};
%you have to plot the extremes of the plot to get the same scale to ...
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigsmallfirstA] table[x index=0, y index=2] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigsmallfirstB] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigsmallsecondA] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigsmallsecondB] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data.dat};
\addplot[myblue,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=bigsmallfirstA and bigsmallfirstB];
\addplot[myred,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=bigsmallsecondA and bigsmallsecondB];


\nextgroupplot[
ymax = 0.35,
ymin = -0.05,
ytick= {0,0.1,0.2,0.3},
minor y tick num = {1},
%~ xtick ={1000,5000},
xtick ={0,5218,10436,15654},
xticklabels={$0$,$100$,$200$,$300$}
]
\addplot[color=myblue, line width = 1.0] table[x index=0, y index=1] {data2.dat};
\addplot[color=myred, line width = 1.0,loosely dashed] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data2.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigbigfirstA] table[x index=0, y index=2] {data2.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigbigfirstB] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data2.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigbigsecondA] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data2.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=bigbigsecondB] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data2.dat};
\addplot[myblue,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=bigbigfirstA and bigbigfirstB];
\addplot[myred,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=bigbigsecondA and bigbigsecondB];

\nextgroupplot[
ymax = 0.08,
ymin = -0.005,
ytick= {0,0.03,0.06},
minor y tick num = {1},
%~ xtick ={1000,7000},
xtick ={0,5218,10436,15654},
xticklabels={$0$,$100$,$200$,$300$}
]
\addplot[color=myblue, line width = 1.0] table[x index=0, y index=1] {data3.dat};
\addplot[color=myred, line width = 1.0,loosely dashed] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data3.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallsmallfirstA] table[x index=0, y index=2] {data3.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallsmallfirstB] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data3.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallsmallsecondA] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data3.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallsmallsecondB] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data3.dat};
\addplot[myblue,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=smallsmallfirstA and smallsmallfirstB];
\addplot[myred,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=smallsmallsecondA and smallsmallsecondB];

\nextgroupplot[
ymax = 0.08,
ymin = -0.005,
ytick= {0,0.03,0.06},
minor y tick num = {1},
%~ xtick ={1000,7000},
xtick ={0,5218,10436,15654},
xticklabels={$0$,$100$,$200$,$300$}
]
\addplot[color=myblue, line width = 1] table[x index=0, y index=1] {data4.dat};
\addplot[color=myred, line width = 1,loosely dashed] table[x index=0, y index=4] {data4.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallbigfirstA] table[x index=0, y index=2] {data4.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallbigfirstB] table[x index=0, y index=3] {data4.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallbigsecondA] table[x index=0, y index=5] {data4.dat};
\addplot[draw=none, name path global=smallbigsecondB] table[x index=0, y index=6] {data4.dat};
\addplot[myblue,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=smallbigfirstA and smallbigfirstB];
\addplot[myred,fill opacity=0.2] fill between[of=smallbigsecondA and smallbigsecondB];
\end{groupplot}

\node at (group c1r1.west) [xshift=-1.7cm,anchor=center, rotate=90] {\bfseries{high prevalence}};
\node at (group c1r2.west) [xshift=-1.7cm,anchor=center, rotate=90] {\bfseries{low prevalence}};
\node at (group c1r1.north) [yshift= 0.7 cm, anchor=center] {\bfseries{second strain with 0\% advantage}};
\node at (group c2r1.north) [yshift= 0.7 cm, anchor=center] {\bfseries{second strain with 25\% advantage}};

\node at (group c1r1.north west) [xshift=0cm,yshift=0.35cm,anchor=north east]{\bfseries{(a)}};
\node at (group c2r1.north west) [xshift=0cm,yshift=0.35cm,anchor=north east]{\bfseries{(b)}};
\node at (group c1r2.north west) [xshift=0cm,yshift=0.35cm,anchor=north east]{\bfseries{(c)}};
\node at (group c2r2.north west) [xshift=0cm,yshift=0.35cm,anchor=north east]{\bfseries{(d)}};
\end{tikzpicture}

%~ \end{preview}
\end{document}
```

On my older setup v1.10, this produces this (this is the [log](http://fbence.web.elte.hu/mwe_old.log) with \listfiles):

[image]

While on the new setup v1.12, it produces this (this is the [log](http://fbence.web.elte.hu/mwe.log) with \listfiles):

[image]

If I comment out all the lines related to drawing the fillbetween stuff (i.e. every \addplot except the first two in every groupplot) I get the same on both setups.

[image]

Now I understand that using a newer pgfplots might cause a problem, but that is why I have the compat set to a specific version, so I am really at a loss, as to why this is happening. What might be causing the problem?

Comment: I put \pgfplotsversion in the file. The old setup is ofcourse 1.10, but the new is 1.12 even though the log says "Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': you might be
nefit from \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} (current compat level: 1.10).." Interesting...

Comment: Maybe the question should be rephrased: why is the `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}` overridden? And what's the new way of doing the same thing?

Comment: I'm voting to leave closed: the accepted answer at the dupe explains "why doesn't using `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}` solve this?" (Bug in `pgfplots`.) Also, [Christian's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207450/fillbetween-from-pgfplots-does-not-work-inside-groupplots#comment496642_212005) on that answer gives a workaround. I tested this workaround with your code and it gives the expected results.