# Multiple axis and filling between curves

Tags: fillbetween

I am currently using multiple `axis` environments in a single `tikzpicture` environment. It all works quite well. However, if I want to fill the area between two curves, only the first call of `fill between` is executed. 
Using the command twice in one `axis` environment works.

The following code returns two identical plots, where only in the left window the area between the lines is filled.

Do I have to reset `fill between` in some way?

Issue appeared with `pgfplots v1.12`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=150mm, paperheight=80mm, margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
shift={(0cm,0cm)},
xlabel=x, ylabel=y,
xmin = -10, xmax = 10, ymin = -10, ymax =10, 
width=5cm, height=5cm, 
scale only axis=true,
]
\addplot[name path=A, black, dashed, ultra thick] coordinates { (-5,5) (5,5) };
\addplot[name path=B, black, dashed, ultra thick] coordinates {(-5,-5) (5,-5)};
\addplot[gray] fill between[of=A and B];
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
shift={(7cm,0cm)},
xlabel=x, ylabel=y,
xmin = -10, xmax = 10, ymin = -10, ymax =10, 
width=5cm, height=5cm, 
scale only axis=true,
]
\addplot[name path=C, black, dashed, ultra thick] coordinates { (-5,5) (5,5) };
\addplot[name path=D, black, dashed, ultra thick] coordinates {(-5,-5) (5,-5)};
\addplot[gray] fill between[of=C and D];
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

As mentioned below, here is an MWE with `groupplots` and version 1.13 which does have the very same issue:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween,groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1}]
\nextgroupplot
    \addplot[name path=A] coordinates { (-5,5) (5,5) };
    \addplot[name path=B] coordinates {(-5,-5) (5,-5)};
    \addplot[gray] fill between[of=A and B];
\nextgroupplot
    \addplot[name path=C] coordinates { (-5,5) (5,5) };
    \addplot[name path=D] coordinates {(-5,-5) (5,-5)};
    \addplot[red] fill between[of=C and D];
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was just testing with `grouplots`, it doesn't. Either I'm missing something, or it's a bug.

Comment: Apparently [Christian fixed it with the `1.13` version](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286771/4778) but the comment below the answer shows that something is still there.

Comment: Tested with 1.13 and it does not work. Stefan, I add an MWE using `groupplots` to your question if you don't mind. Just to have it all in one place. If you don't want this, pls feel free to roll back.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the groupplot discussion. Adding `set layers,cell picture=true` to the axis switches solved it.