# How I can do this without using the groupplot library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, groupplots

I'm trying to make this set of figures but the groupplot library does not respond well with filling functions ([This page explains this fact](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207450/fillbetween-from-pgfplots-does-not-work-inside-groupplots)). But if I use clean TikZ code this filling works well, but I do not know how to put the figures as follows.

[image: option 1]

or

[image: option 2]

thanks for your help...

Comment: I you want to want to align the boundaries, all you need is \centering, \hfil, \hfill, \sbox (or \settowidth) and maybe a minipage.  If you want to align the axis boxes, you will need to do some calculations.

Comment: Pgfplots v1.14 is out, and it solves the problem with `fill between` and `groupplot`.

Comment: A [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) would be nice!

Comment: All I see is empty boxes. Why do you need TikZ or any special library for that? Even if the boxes represent things containing plots, arranging them doesn't require either of those packages as @JohnKormylo says.